# what is the function to sum rows in data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I want to sum rows based on two different categorical columns.
my data is like this :

```
df <- data.frame(country = c('US', 'US', 'US', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK'),
             team = c('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2'),
             x1990 = c(4, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 12),
             x2005 = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7))
```

and I want to prepare it like this:

```
df_sum <- data.frame(country = c('US', 'US', 'UK','UK'),
                 team = c('A', 'B','B', 'C'),
                 x1990 = c(11, 8,16,21),
                 x2005 = c(6, 4,10, 14))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `dplyr` like

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(team = sub("^([[:alpha:]]*).*", "\\1", team)) %>%
  group_by(country, team) %>%
  summarize(across(where(is.numeric), sum)) %>%
  arrange(desc(country))

  country team  x1990 x2005
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 US      A        11     6
2 US      B         8     4
3 UK      B        16    10
4 UK      C        21    14
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I run the code you wrote and I received this error: Error in `across()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: @Arwen Does it print same eroor if you try `dplyr::summarize`, not `summarize`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Now I also want to sum some specific rows by my chose (they are not like A1, A2 ,...). what modifications should I add to the previous code? Like 'df_new <- data.frame(country = c('US', 'US','US', 'UK','UK','UK'),
                     team = c('A', 'B','C','A','F', 'E'),
                     x1990 = c(11, 8,2,16,1,21),
                     x2005 = c(6, 4,2,10,1, 14))


df_sum <- data.frame(country = c('US','US', 'UK','UK'),
                     team = c('A', 'B','A','F'),
                     x1990 = c(11, 10,16,22),
                     x2005 = c(6, 6,10, 15))'

Comment: @Arwen It is hard to catch your question by comment...Would you mind opening another thread/question about that?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're after, as some of the information in "Team" is lost (the digits are ignored), but this provides your expected output with your example input:

```r
df <- data.frame(country = c('US', 'US', 'US', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK'),
                 team = c('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2'),
                 x1990 = c(4, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 12),
                 x2005 = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7))
df
#>   country team x1990 x2005
#> 1      US   A1     4     3
#> 2      US   A2     7     3
#> 3      US   B1     8     4
#> 4      UK   B1     8     4
#> 5      UK   B2     8     6
#> 6      UK   C1     9     7
#> 7      UK   C2    12     7

df_sum <- data.frame(country = c('US', 'US', 'UK','UK'),
                     team = c('A', 'B','B', 'C'),
                     x1990 = c(11, 8,16,21),
                     x2005 = c(6, 4,10, 14))
df_sum
#>   country team x1990 x2005
#> 1      US    A    11     6
#> 2      US    B     8     4
#> 3      UK    B    16    10
#> 4      UK    C    21    14

aggregate(df[,3:4], by = list(df$country, gsub("\\d+", "", df$team)), FUN = sum) 
#>   Group.1 Group.2 x1990 x2005
#> 1      US       A    11     6
#> 2      UK       B    16    10
#> 3      US       B     8     4
#> 4      UK       C    21    14
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

You also probably want to sort the 'new' dataframe and relabel the columns:

```r
df2 <- aggregate(df[,3:4], by = list(df$country, gsub("\\d+", "", df$team)), FUN = sum)
colnames(df2) <- c("Country", "Team", "x1990", "x2005")
df2[order(df2$Country, decreasing = TRUE),]
#>   Country Team x1990 x2005
#> 1      US    A    11     6
#> 3      US    B     8     4
#> 2      UK    B    16    10
#> 4      UK    C    21    14
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(country = c('US', 'US', 'US', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK'),
             team = c('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2'),
             x1990 = c(4, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 12),
             x2005 = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7))
```

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(teams = sub("[0-9]" , "" , team)) %>%
 group_by(country,teams) %>% summarise(x1990 = sum(x1990) , x2005 = sum(x2005)) %>%
 arrange(desc(country))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   country [2]
  country teams x1990 x2005
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 US      A        11     6
2 US      B         8     4
3 UK      B        16    10
4 UK      C        21    14
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I run the code you wrote and I received this error: Error in desc(country) : object 'country' not found

Comment: Using your data i get the answer , try it again

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = is.numeric, by = .(country, team = str_extract(team, "[[:alpha:]]+"))]
```

**Output**

```
   country   team x1990 x2005
    <char> <char> <num> <num>
1:      US      A    11     6
2:      US      B     8     4
3:      UK      B    16    10
4:      UK      C    21    14
```

**Data**

```
df<- structure(list(country = c("US", "US", "US", "UK", "UK", "UK", 
"UK"), team = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"), x1990 = c(4, 
7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 12), x2005 = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```